# Active Admin, one page - two diffrent forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have following two resources:

1. Position
2. JobTitle

And a position `belongs_to` job title.

In page Position, I create new position, with `job_title` select and some other selects. I need also create new `job_title` in this page, instead of choose select variants. So, in fact, or I choose job title in existing base, or create new, and save it for this position.

How can I make this? I looking for answer, and reading docs, but nothing!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`fields_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) in your **view** to send `params` for two models at a time.

Here's how I would try to solve to problem:

```
<%= form_for @job_title do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
   </p>
   <p>
     <%= f.label :description %><br />
     <%= f.text_field :description %>
   </p>
  <%= f.fields_for :position do |builder| %>
    <p>                                                                   
      <%= builder.label :name %> <br />                                   
      <%= builder.text_field :name %>                                     
    </p>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

And then, in your controller, you need to create the association. For more information, you can check out the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?) for nested forms.